# Several SUM from several tables

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I guess I can't formulate my question right so here comes my SQL problem.
I run the following query:

```
SELECT P.ORDER_NO, P.LINE_NO, P.RELEASE_NO, SUM(P.BUY_QTY_DUE) 
FROM PURCHASE_ORDER_LINE_ALL P
WHERE P.CONTRACT='APC32' AND P.PART_NO='900-0089' AND ORDER_NO='38288'
GROUP BY P.ORDER_NO, P.LINE_NO, P.RELEASE_NO;
```

Result becomes:

```
ORDER_NO LINE_NO RELEASE_NO SUM(P.BUY_QTY_DUE)
38288    1       1          140
```

The second query is:

```
SELECT R.ORDER_NO, R.LINE_NO, R.RELEASE_NO, SUM(R.INV_QTY_ARRIVED)
FROM PURCHASE_RECEIPT_NEW R
WHERE R.ORDER_NO='38288' AND R.LINE_NO='1' AND R.RELEASE_NO='1' 
GROUP BY R.ORDER_NO, R.LINE_NO, R.RELEASE_NO;
```

And result:

```
ORDER_NO LINE_NO RELEASE_NO SUM(R.INV_QTY_ARRIVED)
38288    1       1          140
```

If I use the following the result is obviously wrong. How can I get a result like:

```
ORDER_NO LINE_NO RELEASE_NO SUM(P.BUY_QTY_DUE) SUM(R.INV_QTY_ARRIVED)
38288    1       1          140                140
```

```
SELECT P.ORDER_NO, P.LINE_NO, P.RELEASE_NO, SUM(P.BUY_QTY_DUE), SUM(R.INV_QTY_ARRIVED)
FROM 
PURCHASE_ORDER_LINE_ALL P
LEFT JOIN PURCHASE_RECEIPT_NEW R
ON P.ORDER_NO=R.ORDER_NO AND P.LINE_NO=R.LINE_NO AND P.RELEASE_NO=R.RELEASE_NO
WHERE P.CONTRACT='APC32' AND P.PART_NO='900-0089' AND R.ORDER_NO='38288' AND R.LINE_NO='1' AND R.RELEASE_NO='1' 
GROUP BY P.ORDER_NO, P.LINE_NO, P.RELEASE_NO;
```

Wrong result, sort of:

```
ORDER_NO LINE_NO RELEASE_NO SUM(P.BUY_QTY_DUE) SUM(R.INV_QTY_ARRIVED)
38288    1       1          420                140
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Didn't you notice in the preview panel that the question was barely readable? ;-) You can format source code with the [Code Sample `{}`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VYd26.png) toolbar button. I've done it for you this time.

Comment: Sorry, my first entry here. I will shape up. Thank's for your help. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT P.ORDER_NO, P.LINE_NO, P.RELEASE_NO, SUM(P.BUY_QTY_DUE) 
FROM PURCHASE_ORDER_LINE_ALL P
WHERE P.CONTRACT='APC32' AND P.PART_NO='900-0089' AND ORDER_NO='38288'
GROUP BY P.ORDER_NO, P.LINE_NO, P.RELEASE_NO;
UNION/UNION ALL
SELECT 0, 0, 0,0, SUM(R.INV_QTY_ARRIVED)
FROM PURCHASE_RECEIPT_NEW R
WHERE R.ORDER_NO='38288' AND R.LINE_NO='1' AND R.RELEASE_NO='1' 
GROUP BY R.ORDER_NO, R.LINE_NO, R.RELEASE_NO;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I had to modify it somewhat to work. But results in two rows, not one. `SELECT P.ORDER_NO, P.LINE_NO, P.RELEASE_NO, SUM(P.BUY_QTY_DUE) 
FROM PURCHASE_ORDER_LINE_ALL P
WHERE P.CONTRACT='APC32' AND P.PART_NO='900-0089' AND P.ORDER_NO='38288'
GROUP BY P.ORDER_NO, P.LINE_NO, P.RELEASE_NO
UNION
SELECT '0','0','0', SUM(R.INV_QTY_ARRIVED)
FROM PURCHASE_RECEIPT_NEW R
WHERE R.ORDER_NO='38288' AND R.LINE_NO='1' AND R.RELEASE_NO='1' 
GROUP BY R.ORDER_NO, R.LINE_NO, R.RELEASE_NO` `ORDER_NO LINE_NO RELEASE_NO SUM(P.BUY_QTY_DUE)
0 0 0 140
38288 1 1 140
`

Answer (score 1):

group the two and then join them.

```
select pal.order_no,pal.line_no,pal.release_no,pal.sum_buy_qty_due,prn.sum_inv_qty_arrived
  from (select P.order_no,P.line_no,P.release_no,
               sum(P.buy_qty_due) sum_buy_qty_due
          from purchase_order_line_all P
         where P.contract = 'APC32'
           and P.part_no = '900-0089'
           and order_no = '38288'
         group by P.order_no,P.line_no,P.release_no) pal
       inner join (select R.order_no,R.line_no,R.release_no,
                          sum(R.inv_qty_arrived) sum_inv_qty_arrived
                     from purchase_receipt_new R
                    where R.order_no = '38288'
                      and R.line_no = '1'
                      and R.release_no = '1'
                    group by R.order_no,R.line_no,R.release_no) prn
               on prn.order_no = pal.order_no 
                  and prn.line_no = pal.line_no 
                  and prn.release_no = pal.release_no
```

example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/87d9b/1

Comment: That was the solution. Thank you! :)

Comment: For the data that you gave in the question, this answer works, but it will only work for rows where the order, line and release exist on BOTH tables because of the inner join. If this isn't the case you'll need an outer join or even a full outer join but that obviously depends on your data. Depending on the circumstances, I would sometimes do this and sometimes use `UNION` like @spin_eight has done.

Answer (score 0):

Query:

```
SELECT P.ORDER_NO,
       P.LINE_NO,
       P.RELEASE_NO,
       SUM(P.BUY_QTY_DUE) AS  SUMBUY_QTY_DUE,
       (SELECT SUM(R.INV_QTY_ARRIVED)
        FROM PURCHASE_RECEIPT_NEW R
        WHERE R.ORDER_NO=P.ORDER_NO
          AND R.LINE_NO=P.LINE_NO
          AND R.RELEASE_NO=P.RELEASE_NO) AS SUMINV_QTY_ARRIVED
FROM PURCHASE_ORDER_LINE_ALL P
WHERE P.CONTRACT='APC32'
  AND P.PART_NO='900-0089'
  AND ORDER_NO='38288'
GROUP BY P.ORDER_NO,
         P.LINE_NO,
         P.RELEASE_NO
```